# Increment static variable value in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt

In my XSLT 2.0 file, I have to define a  static variable say counter and will be using this variable under a for-each() loop. I need to increment this static variable value by 10.

Says for each look, this variable value should be in incremented by 10,20,30,40.
Internally I will be assigning this variable to one of target schema element.

Can someone please hep or help me redirecting to relevant post.

Comment: There won't be a relevant post for this, as XSLT is a functional language, and variables are "immutable" in it, meaning they can't be changed once set. Instead of saying how you are trying to solve a particular problem, you say what your problem is, as it can probably be solved in a different way, that may need not variables at all. (Possibly by using the `position()` function for example). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to increment a variable within a `xsl:for-each` loop, because **`xsl:for-each` is not a loop**<sup>1</sup>.

You could, however, use the `position()` function to increase a static variable incrementally, e.g.:

```
$staticVariable + 10 * position()
```

--
[1] Except: http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!extensions/instructions/assign